# What the source and dest parameters of InputFilter.filter method represents?

Tags: android

What the source and dest parameters of InputFilter.filter method represents? I guess source is the value we enter in the input filed... but dest???

Thanks

@Thanks to all for your comments/answers.

After a little play with inputfilter I understand that the source and dest parameters of the InputFilter.filter method represents,

```
    source -  have the current input character of the user input
    dest   -  have the current value of the EditText/TextView
```

Please correct me if I were wrong

Thanks

Comment: Please read the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html

Comment: @MByD - Thanks. That's the first trial I did. the doesn't give any explanation of what is the source and dest for.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that can help you: http://blog.mobile-j.de/2009/12/i-really-like-androids-edittext.html